# What is wrong with my closure?

Tags: swift, closures

```
    let asdf = {

        println("df")

        for i in 1...10 {

        }
    }
```

> Can not convert expression's type '() -> () -> ST0' to type '() -> ()
>   -> ST0'

What is the problem with upper closure. If I remove for loop it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why that syntax doesn't work (I too would have thought it should), but it's a simplified case of the full syntax

```
let asdf = { () -> () in
            println("df")

            for i in 1...10 {
                println(i)
            }
        }

asdf()
```

which does work.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not in a context to expect a closure, it's not interpreting it as one.

By declaring asdf to be a closure, it now expects a closure so accepts the abbreviated syntax:

```
let asdf :()->() = {

    println("df")

    for i in 1...10 {
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the full syntax as Grimxn points out.